# I have a problem to create function my database in oracle

Tags: oracle, function

I have a problem with functions in oracle.
I am trying to add a new row to an existing table but I don't know if I'm going the right direction all the time I have an error.
The function worked in Postgresql and now wants to transform it into Oracle.

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_human(
   first_name VARCHAR(15),
   last_name VARCHAR (15), 
   birthday DATE, 
   pesel BIGINT, 
   employee_function(VARCHAR(15))
RETURNS void AS 
$$ BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO WORKERS(first_name, last_name, birthday, pesel, employee_function) 
  VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5); END; $$ LANGUAGE  plpgsql;
```

Select:

```
select add_human(‘John’,’Wick’,’1971-01-27’,’71012745639’,’Actor’);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Oracle, you'd use a **procedure** to insert rows into a table, not a function (they are to be used to *return* certain value).

That would be something like this:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_human
  2    (
  3     p_first_name        in VARCHAR2,
  4     p_last_name         in VARCHAR2,
  5     p_birthday          in DATE,
  6     p_pesel             in NUMBER,
  7     p_employee_function in VARCHAR2
  8    )
  9  AS
 10  BEGIN
 11    INSERT INTO WORKERS
 12      (first_name, last_name, birthday, pesel, employee_function)
 13    VALUES (p_first_name, p_last_name, p_birthday, p_pesel, p_employee_function);
 14  END add_human;
 15  /

Procedure created.

SQL> BEGIN
  2    add_human('John', 'Wick', date '1971-01-27', 71012745639, 'Actor');
  3  END;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT * FROM workers;

FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME  BIRTHDAY            PESEL EMPLOYEE_F
---------- ---------- ---------- -------------- ----------
John       Wick       1971-01-27    71012745639 Actor

SQL>
```